# RegEx search to ignore words in a string

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have a file with thousands of entries of server names, but I want to ignore any server as shown below:

```
bnn6122.fdw.dee.corp;
ao.d33fegd.ao.dee.corp;
ao.d55fegd.ao.dee.corp;
qrwafgwd00846.fdw.dee.corp;
kdgf9934.wdf.dee.corp
```

Their values of number differ but characters stay the same.

I tried the the following code but it returns a blank list:

```
re.findall(r'^(?!bnn[0-9]|^ao*|^qrwafgwd[0-9]|^kdgf[0-9])\w+(.wdf.dee.corp)', f, re.M|re.I)
```

If I ignore the above server I should still get around 3000 servers in the list. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: post a sample string along with expected output.

Comment: @AvinashRaj in the above list i need to ignore the above servers and get all the other names in the file, which has servers like pd7343.fdw.dee.corp; ko8383.fdw.dee.corp

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a negative look-ahead anchored at the start:

```
^(?!(?:bnn\d+\.fdw|ao\.d\d+fegd\.ao|qrwafgwd\d+\.fdw|kdgf\d+\.wdf)\.dee\.corp)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/aI6eD9/3)

The `^` anchor starts searching from the start of a string (use `re.M` if you need to search from the start of a line), then the `(?!...)` lookahead will make sure there are no occurrences of the substrings in the alternation group right in the beginning. The common part - `dee.corp` - is out of the group since it is a common ending.

Note that `ao.d33fegd.ao.dee.corp` and `ao.d55fegd.ao.dee.corp` follow the same pattern, thus it is possible to shorten the regex even more.

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?!(?:bnn[0-9]|ao.*|qrwafgwd[0-9]|kdgf[0-9]))\w+(?:\.wdf\.dee\.corp)
```

Try this.See demo.Escape the `.`.

https://regex101.com/r/hF7zZ1/1

Comment: thank you , but the in the regex101.com site [link](https://regex101.com/r/hF7zZ1/1) the server names are ignored and only the last 3 entries(.wdf.dee.corp) are displayed, how can I tweak the code to get the full fqdn names .

and thank you for the link, that will really help in learning re further .